# launch a web page automatically NativeScript

Tags: html, typescript, angular, nativescript, mobile-development

There is a website of the company, when you open it for the first time the login page opens automatically. I'm going to build the mobile version of it. So I want when the app is opened, that login page will be launched. How do I get started? Do i need to use auto-launch? or Do i need to set the page manually like using openURL etc?

Is there typescript alternative for this:

```
// my-page.js
var OpenUrl = require("nativescript-openurl");
OpenUrl("http://www.master-technology.com");
```

Or should I use WebView? If so, how to make it launch automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If yоu are using web-view all you need to do is to pass your url and it will load it on the fly

```
<WebView url="https://www.nativescript.org" width="*" height="*"/>
```

Of course, you can bind to your web-view url property and pass the source dynamically.

There is also a plugin called [nativescript-webview-interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-webview-interface) which can ease your bi-directional communication. Nice tutorial for this plugin can be found [here](http://shripalsoni.com/blog/nativescript-webview-native-bi-directional-communication/)